# Вывод списка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join, print

Как мне вывести список
`['□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□']` 
в одну строчку без **`[]`**, '**`,`**' и **`''`** то есть

> До - ['□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□']
>
> После □□□□□□□□□□□□□□

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myList = ['□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□','□']

print(myList)
['□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□', '□']

print(*myList)
□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □

print(''.join(myList))
□□□□□□□□□□□□□□

print(*myList, sep='', end='') # Без пробелов и завершающего переноса строки. 
□□□□□□□□□□□□□□
```

Comment: А можно как то убрать или уменьшить расстояние между символами?

Comment: @Terrorka можно

Comment: А......... как?

Comment: @Terrorka  я добавил а ответ `print(''.join(myList))`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выводить с разделителями следует указать разделитель в значении аргумента sep
Например,

```
print(*[1,2,3,4,5],sep=' --- ')
```

выведет

1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5

есть также аргумент end -- это значение, которое будет добавлено в вывод в конце